# Why isn't a registered UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification always called?

Tags: cocoa-touch, notifications, orientation, uitableview, uidevice

I wrote a simple view controller that shows a modal popup dialog. Because it creates a new window to lay over the entire screen, I've added a `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` observer that figures out how to rotate the view using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()`. And it seems to work.

*Mostly.* The downside is that I can fiddle with the orientation and get it to end up sideways or upside down. Check out [this 18s video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVfCZP3ux_Q) demonstrating the issue. In debugging, it appears that sometimes the notification doesn't fire, or at least doesn't call the callback method that's listening for it.

I must be missing something, though, because if you look at the video again, you'll notice that the view behind it *does* rotate properly. That one is managed by `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`. How is it that the iOS controller method is always called properly (presumably managed by a `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` observer in UIViewController) but my own code is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by eliminating the use of `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`. What I do instead is create a subclass of `UIViewController` and make set the custom view to its view. It then simply implements `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to do the rotation. This is actually less finicky code for me. It does feel like a hack, though, to create an arbitrary `UIViewController` just to take advantage of autorotation in what is essentially a clone of `presentModalViewController`. Seems like `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` ought to work properly. I expect there is a way to make it behave, but I've yet to find it. :-(

Comment: Note that `-presentModalViewController` does take a *controller*. The events are sent to controllers within the main window. UIWindow contains an array of root controllers, but for some reason only forwards these events to the first item in that list... :o(

Comment: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification is called too many time. The solution of Jim is much better.

Comment: @Vinzius—I tried to adapt my class to use Jim's solution, but could not get it to work. It still would rotate in appropriately, as you can see in the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_IvFAkdfuA) I posted using his solution. Believe me, I would rather have used that approach than this workaround.

Answer (score 12):

I used `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` in Kobo, which appears to do the trick. It's a lot more reliable, because you want to match the UI's chosen orientation, not necessarily where the device happens to be. In other words, you can let Apple decide when you should re-orient your window.

Here are a few snippets from the Kobo app's popup dialog code on the iPad (UIAlertView looks kinda dinky on iPad, so [Richard Penner](http://twitter.com/richardpenner) wrote a better one). After a few glitches with more recent iOS versions and having to display these dialogs in different situations (all around orientation IIRC), I had to tweak it to sit directly inside the UIWindow, which meant duplicating all the orientation transformation logic.

This code comes from a UIViewController whose view gets dropped straight onto the current window.

```
- (void) presentDialogWindow
{
    // register for orientation change notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(orientationWillChange:)
                                                 name: UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                               object: nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(orientationDidChange:)
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                               object: nil];
}

- (void) orientationWillChange: (NSNotification *) note
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation current = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[[note userInfo] objectForKey: UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    if ( [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: orientation] == NO )
        return;

    if ( current == orientation )
        return;

    // direction and angle
    CGFloat angle = 0.0;
    switch ( current )
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        {
            switch ( orientation )
            {
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                    angle = (CGFloat)M_PI;  // 180.0*M_PI/180.0 == M_PI
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                    angle = (CGFloat)(M_PI*-90.0)/180.0;
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                    angle = (CGFloat)(M_PI*90.0)/180.0;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
            break;
        }
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        {
            switch ( orientation )
            {
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                    angle = (CGFloat)M_PI;  // 180.0*M_PI/180.0 == M_PI
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                    angle = (CGFloat)(M_PI*90.0)/180.0;
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                    angle = (CGFloat)(M_PI*-90.0)/180.0;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
            break;
        }
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        {
            switch ( orientation )
            {
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                    angle = (CGFloat)M_PI;  // 180.0*M_PI/180.0 == M_PI
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                    angle = (CGFloat)(M_PI*-90.0)/180.0;
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                    angle = (CGFloat)(M_PI*90.0)/180.0;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
            break;
        }
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        {
            switch ( orientation )
            {
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                    angle = (CGFloat)M_PI;  // 180.0*M_PI/180.0 == M_PI
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                    angle = (CGFloat)(M_PI*-90.0)/180.0;
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                    angle = (CGFloat)(M_PI*90.0)/180.0;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( angle );

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"" context: NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.4];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.view.transform, rotation);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) orientationDidChange: (NSNotification *) note
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[[note userInfo] objectForKey: UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    if ( [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]] == NO )
        return;

    self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    [self didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: orientation];
}
```

We use it by loading this view controller, adding its view to a window, then calling -presentModalDialog, like so:

```
UIView *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubview: theController.view];
[theController presentDialogWindow];
```

I'm going to make a simple UIViewController subclass to implement the fiddly bits soon, and will post it on my github account. When I do, I'll edit this & link to it.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that looks like it would do the trick nicely `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` is clearly the key. I'll have to give it a try when I have some spare cycles. I was also creating a UIViewController subclass for this, with `-presentPopupViewController` and `-dismissPopupViewController` methods. It also respects `contentSizeForViewInPopover` in determining the size to present. Will have to merge with your code once you post it. :-)

Comment: Okay, just tried this solution. Now I'm pretty well-convinced I must be doing something else wrong, because it's not working. Check out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_IvFAkdfuA) (22s) of my popup view using it. Gah!

Answer (score 0):

UIDeviceOrientation has a few values that don't map to UIInterfaceOrientation:

```
UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,              // Device oriented flat, face up
UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown             // Device oriented flat, face down
```

Is it possible that the notification callback is firing, but these cases aren't handled?

If the view controller has access to the window - it can forward the didRotate callback to the window manually.

Comment: Alas, no. I'm actually using `self.interfaceOrientation` rather than the UIDeviceOrientation, because when I check the latter, it's *way* to sensitive. It changes the orientation at the slightest movement of the device. That is, the problem is *far* worse when I use the UIDeviceOrientation.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I instead call `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` from the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` callback method? That might be nice, but alas it appears that my notification method either is not called by the system or else `self.interfaceOrientation` is the wrong value, and that's what leads it to get out of whack.

Comment: I see - not sure why the notifications wouldn't be received. In any case, the willRotate/didRotate methods of the auto-rotating UIViewController should be a reliable time to manually rotate the modal dialog.